# How to get TD cell values using jquery from a Data Webpart

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery

I would like to get the text from the first and second TD which has the class user and id

```
<tr class="rowid">
    <td class="user">A</td>
    <td class="id">B</td>
</tr>
```

So first i want A and then B
I tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".rowid").each(function(index, value) { 
var test= $(.user).text();
alert(test);
```

But i get A twice.I want one value at a time.
Any ideas what 'm doing wrong?
Cheers

Comment: Here's complete tutorial how to get table cell TD value http://codepedia.info/jquery-get-table-cell-td-value-div/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code is always pointing to A:

```
var test = $(".user").text()
```

instead use:

```
$(".rowid").find("td").each(function() {
  var test = $(this).text();
  alert(test);
}
```

this will iterate over the td elements and output the text.

To get each value:

```
$(".rowid").each(function() {
  var a = $(this).find(".user").text();
  var b = $(this).find(".id").text();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Russel I do i get "A" and "B"
seperately.
Chrs

Comment: I have added a block of code so you can iterate over each tr element and return the user and id (A and B text) for each one.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: Chrs Russell.
Hope to be on top off Jquery soon

Comment: No worries. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

First selector ".rowid" selects all tags with class "rowid". At you markup example it's only one tr tag, so you will itterate by `each` function only through one element. Second selector ".user" gives you **all** tags with class "user", but if you want to take A and then B, will need to take all `td` tags of current `tr` container or select ".user" `td` and ".id" `td` seperatly as in example below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    rows = $(".rowid").each(function(index,value){
            user = $(value).children(".user").text();
            id = $(value).children(".id").text();
            alert(id+'\t'+user);
    });
});
```

Comment: IAfanasov thanks tried it but didn't work

Answer (score 1):

```
<table id ="table1">
    <th>UserName</th>
    <th>Password</th>
    <tr>
        <td id = "1">username</td>
        <td id = "2">12344</td>
    </tr>
</table>

$('#table1 tr').each(function (){
    var vara = $(this).find('#2').html();
    if(vara != null)
        alert($(this).find('#2').html());
});
```

Comment: Please add some explanation when answering, rather than just dropping a code fragment. This will make your answer much more useful. Thanks.